# get Data from FirebaseStorage in a Struct

Tags: swift, struct, firebase-storage

Here is my challenge: I have a Struct. This gets initialized with a documentSnapshot from FirebaseDatabase. The Struct returns a Array which then gets populated in a Collection View

This worked fine, until the point I tried to add two images to the array. They are stored in Firebase Storage. The references keys are passed into the struct when initialized (They are there, this I tested). However, when myArray is created, the images are not there. There is no error message. All other parts of the struct/array work fine (distance calculation etc.)

Thanks for anybody's help

```
struct myStruct {

    var myArray = [Any]()

    init?(Name: String, Amount: String, Description: String, SecondName: String, RID: String, GeoPoint: GeoPoint, DID: String) {

        var location = CLLocation()
        var myArray = [Any]()
        var distance: Double
        var imageA = UIImage()
        var imageB = UIImage()

        let refA = Storage.storage().reference().child("Images").child(todayDate).child(DID)
        refA.getData(maxSize: 1000 * 1240 * 1240) { data, error in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                imageA = UIImage(data: data!)!
            }
        }

        let refB = Storage.storage().reference().child("Icons").child(RID)
        refB.getData(maxSize: 1000 * 1240 * 1240) { data, error in
            if let error = error { print(error.localizedDescription)
                imageB = (UIImage(named: "DefaultIcon.png") as UIImage?)!
            } else {
                imageB = UIImage(data: data!)!
            }
        }

        location = CLLocation(latitude: GeoPoint.latitude, longitude: GeoPoint.longitude)
        distance = round(location.distance(from: userLocation)/10)*10


        myArray = [Name, Amount, Description, SecondName, String(Int(distance)), GeoPoint, imageA, imageB]

        self.menuItem = menuItem
    }
}
```

Comment: You are missing the asynchone concept. `imageA =` or `imageB` will be set later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your struct, in order to become fully instanciated, needs to wait for two asynchronous data tasks to complete first (fetching the images). Since you start them, but don't wait for them to complete, at the point in time when you write to the array the image data is simply not yet available.

There are a number of possible ways to resolve this kind of temporal dependency. Which one is the right one for your project depends a lot on your use case and overall choice of architecture.

In general, however, it would be a good idea to keep such asynchronous data tasks out of the struct's `init`, and instead perform them in whatever class is responsible for creating and managing your structs. The fetched images could then be passed to the struct as init parameters.

Here's how you could go about it, demonstrated in a slightly abstracted way:

You probably currently have somewhere in your code an object with a function that creates and stores `MyStruct`s similar to this:

```
func loadMyStruct() {
    self.myStruct = MyStruct(...)
}
```

A better alternative to that struct-creating function would be:

```
func loadMyStruct(completion: @escaping ()->Void) {
        DispatchQueue(label: "MyStructDataFetch", attributes: .concurrent).async { [weak self] in // don't block main thread waiting for data tasks to finish
            let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup() // since we're waiting on two parallel async tasks, we can use a DispatchGroup to group them together

            var imageA: UIImage?
            var imageB: UIImage?

            dispatchGroup.enter() // enter DispatchGroup
            let refA = Storage.storage().reference().child("Images").child(todayDate).child(DID)
            refA.getData(maxSize: 1000 * 1240 * 1240) { data, error in // start 1st data task

                if let error = error {
                    ...
                } else {
                    imageA = UIImage(data: data!)!
                }

                dispatchGroup.leave() // 1st task is done; leave DispatchGroup
            }

            dispatchGroup.enter() // enter DispatchGroup
            let refB = Storage.storage().reference().child("Icons").child(RID)
            refB.getData(maxSize: 1000 * 1240 * 1240) { data, error in // start 2nd data task

                if let error = error {
                    ...
                } else {
                    imageB = UIImage(data: data!)!
                }
                dispatchGroup.leave() // 2nd task is done; leave DispatchGroup
            }

            let _ = dispatchGroup.wait(timeout: DispatchTime.distantFuture) // wait for all tasks to be done, then...

            self?.myStruct = MyStruct(imageA: imageA, imageB: imageB, ...) // ... pass the finished images to MyStruct constructor
            completion() // Optional: notify observer (e.g. UI) that "MyStruct" is now ready to use
        }
    }
```

With your struct's init adjusted accordingly:

```
init?(imageA: UIImage?, imageB: UIImage?, ...) {
 ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The hint about async already helped. I don't think I can init the struct with the images, because they are unknown at this time. Ahead of this goes a Geofirestore query which returns a array of GeoLocations in range. I iterate over the array and return the array in the struct.